# graph theory and linear algebra

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a flow graph that gives me the flow matrix below. How do I compute $A\odot A$ and $A \odot A \odot A$? I'm not familiar with this operator and can't really find anything about it. The hint that was given is that "Given $A = [a_{ij}]$ and $B = [b_{kl}]$ of size $n × m$ and $m × l$ respectively, we define
$A \odot B= [\max_{1\leq k \leq m} \min(a_{ik},b_{kl})]$."

**MY WORK**
The flow graph I get gives me the flow matrix 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
   2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 4 \\
  \end{array}

**NOV 19**
Using the method below I got

$A\odot A= \begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
   1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 7 \\
   0 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 7 \\
  \end{array}$

$A\odot A\odot A= \begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 7 \\
   0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 7 & 0 & 4 \\
  \end{array}$

Did I make a mistake or are these correct?

Comment: Can you post the entire exact question?

Comment: The characters `` and `` don't render properly on my computer.  What are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition $[A⊙B]_{il}= [\max_{1≤k≤m} \min(a_{ik},b_{kl})]$ is enough for us to compute the desired matrices.  For example: for $A \odot A$, we compute
$$
[A\odot A]_{23} = \max_{1 \leq k \leq 5} \min(a_{2k}, a_{k3})\\
= \max\{\min(3,2),\min(0,8),\min(8,0),\min(1,0), \min(0,10)\} \\
= \max\{2,0,0,0,0)\} = 2
$$
Which is to say that 
$$
A \odot A = \pmatrix{?&?&?&?&?\\
?&?&\color{red}2&?&?\\
?&?&?&?&?\\
?&?&?&?&?\\
?&?&?&?&?\\}
$$
The computation of the remaining entries is similar.

Comment: For A⊙A⊙A, im assuming it would be similar except instead of 2 "leaps" it would be 3?